# How to right use canActivate method in angular2?

Tags: angular

I've read a few articles about angular2 authentication and all of them say something like this:

```
canActivate() {
    return this.user.isloggedIn;
}
```

where isloggedIn is a property of some service:

```
isloggedIn = localStorage.getItem('auth_token');
```

In this case access to route only depends from localstorage variable (auth_token). But user can add this variable to lacalstorage manually in console. 
What is the right usage of this method? Should it make some http request to server and send auth_token to validation?

Comment: That shouldn't be a problem. If the user forges a fake authentication token and stores it in localstorage, he will be able to navigate to hidden routes, which will probably send HTTP requests to the server, which will detect that the token is a fake one, and thus return an error response. Validation and authorization must always be done at server-side.

Comment: So if I want to show/hide a static content (where http is not used)  I have to add some http for validation, right?

Comment: If some content contains something that some users shouldn't see, then it shouldn't be static content, because static content is part of the JavaScript or HTML code that is downloaded by the browser, and anyone can thus look in that code to find the secret. So yes, it should come from the server, once you're sure that the user has the right to see that secret content.

Comment: thanks a lot. And one more question. Should I write user password to jwt? Or how to validate token?

Comment: No, definitely not. Store the user ID, which is public information. A JWT token can't be forged because it's cryptographically signed using your secret key. To validate the token, you parse it and verify the signature. If the signature matches, you can be confident that it hasn't been forged, and can just extract the user ID.

Comment: check this link for implementation http://stackoverflow.com/a/40359140/4793153